# Зачем хранить информацию в реляционной базе данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть такое требование к сайту "информация о пользователях должна храниться в реляционной базе данных". Но почему так должно быть? Каким ещё образом она может храниться?

Comment: В нереляционной базе данных, в текстовом файле, в любом другом файле.

Comment: ... и даже в файловой системе - скажем, отдельный каталог на юзера.

Comment: А как можно обосновать, что хранение в реляционной будет лучше? Разве что удобнее, но как ещё...

Comment: "удобнее" - вполне себе обоснование. Если вы не используете готовую СУБД - то вы создаёте свою СУБД, где много приключений чуть только появляется необходимость не терять данные при сбоях (например, отключение электричества). А уж когда появляется конкурентный доступ... Проведите аналогию с "как обосновать использование готовой ОС вместо разработки собственной"

Answer (score 1):

Не существует баз данных, которые подойдут абсолютно всем. Именно поэтому многие компании используют и реляционные, и нереляционные БД для решения различных задач.

Вот две причины, которые могут послужить поводом для выбора SQL-базы:

1. Необходимость соответствия базы данных требованиям ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability — атомарность, непротиворечивость, изолированность, долговечность). Это позволяет уменьшить вероятность неожиданного поведения системы и обеспечить целостность базы данных. Достигается подобное путём жёсткого определения того, как именно транзакции взаимодействуют с базой данных. Это отличается от подхода, используемого в NoSQL-базах, которые ставят во главу угла гибкость и скорость, а не 100% целостность данных.
2. Данные, с которыми вы работаете, структурированы, при этом структура не подвержена частым изменением. Если ваша организация не находится в стадии экспоненциального роста, вероятно, не найдётся убедительных причин использовать БД, которая позволяет достаточно вольно обращаться с типами данных и нацелена на обработку огромных объёмов информации.

Вот возможности, которые стали причиной популярности таких NoSQL баз данных, как MongoDB, CouchDB, Cassandra, HBase:

1. Хранение больших объёмов неструктурированной информации. База данных NoSQL не накладывает ограничений на типы хранимых данных. Более того, при необходимости в процессе работы можно добавлять новые типы данных.
2. Использование облачных вычислений и хранилищ. Облачные хранилища — отличное решение, но они требуют, чтобы данные можно было легко распределить между несколькими серверами для обеспечения масштабирования. Использование, для тестирования и разработки, локального оборудования, а затем перенос системы в облако, где она и работает — это именно то, для чего созданы NoSQL базы данных.
3. Быстрая разработка. Если вы разрабатываете систему, используя agile-методы, применение реляционной БД способно замедлить работу. NoSQL базы данных не нуждаются в том же объёме подготовительных действий, которые обычно нужны для реляционных баз.

оригинал [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/324936/)